# Aggregated sub query inside other aggregated query

Tags: sql, excel, vba, t-sql

I use Microsoft VBA together with Excel and also use the ADODB connection to treat the Sheet as database. 
I have one issue regarding a SQL aggregated query that uses also aggregated sub queries. The issue is that I cannot use it like this, due to the fact it is throwing errors and I don't know how to change it

The SQL query:

```
Select inv.[Region], inv.[Org Name], inv.[Bill To Customer Number], inv.[Bill To Customer Name], 
SUM(inv.[AR Global Total Amount]) as "Amount Invoiced", 
COUNT(pay.[Sales Invoice Number]) as "Count Invoices", 
SUM(inv.[AR Global Total Amount]*(inv.[Payment Due Fiscal Date]-inv.[Invoiced Fiscal Date])) as "Sum of Terms Mult", 
SUM(inv.[AR Global Total Amount]*(pay.GL_Min-inv.[Invoiced Fiscal Date])) as "Sum of Pay Days Mult", 
SUM(inv.[AR Global Total Amount]*(pay.GL_Min-inv.[Payment Due Fiscal Date])) as "Sum of Days Late Mult" 
FROM 
(
    Select * 
    From [Data$] as inv 
    WHERE [AR Transaction Sub Type] IN ('Inv', 'Inv-T')
) a,
(
    Select [Region], [Org Name], [Bill To Customer Number], [Bill To Customer Name], [Sales Invoice Number], Min([GL Fiscal Date]) as GL_Min 
    FROM [Data$] as pay 
    WHERE [AR Transaction Sub Type] IN ('Cash', 'Cash-T') 
    GROUP BY [Region], [Org Name], [Bill To Customer Number], [Bill To Customer Name], [Sales Invoice Number]
) t  

WHERE inv.[Sales Invoice Number] = pay.[Sales Invoice Number] AND inv.[Org Name] = pay.[Org Name] AND inv.[AR Global Total Amount]>0 
GROUP BY inv.[Region], inv.[Org Name], inv.[Bill To Customer Number], inv.[Bill To Customer Name] 
ORDER BY SUM(inv.[AR Global Total Amount]) DESC
```

The problem is on the second sub query, the one where I try to capture the min date.

Could someone point me to a proper syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: Your query seems correct except subquery alias, could you change a with inv and t with pay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query seems correct except subquery alias. Could you try this?

```
Select inv.[Region], inv.[Org Name], inv.[Bill To Customer Number], inv.[Bill To Customer Name], 
SUM(inv.[AR Global Total Amount]) as "Amount Invoiced", 
COUNT(pay.[Sales Invoice Number]) as "Count Invoices", 
SUM(inv.[AR Global Total Amount]*(inv.[Payment Due Fiscal Date]-inv.[Invoiced Fiscal Date])) as "Sum of Terms Mult", 
SUM(inv.[AR Global Total Amount]*(pay.GL_Min-inv.[Invoiced Fiscal Date])) as "Sum of Pay Days Mult", 
SUM(inv.[AR Global Total Amount]*(pay.GL_Min-inv.[Payment Due Fiscal Date])) as "Sum of Days Late Mult" 
FROM 
(
    Select * 
    From [Data$] as inv 
    WHERE [AR Transaction Sub Type] IN ('Inv', 'Inv-T')
) inv,
(
    Select [Region], [Org Name], [Bill To Customer Number], [Bill To Customer Name], [Sales Invoice Number], Min([GL Fiscal Date]) as GL_Min 
    FROM [Data$] as pay 
    WHERE [AR Transaction Sub Type] IN ('Cash', 'Cash-T') 
    GROUP BY [Region], [Org Name], [Bill To Customer Number], [Bill To Customer Name], [Sales Invoice Number]
) pay  

WHERE inv.[Sales Invoice Number] = pay.[Sales Invoice Number] AND inv.[Org Name] = pay.[Org Name] AND inv.[AR Global Total Amount]>0 
GROUP BY inv.[Region], inv.[Org Name], inv.[Bill To Customer Number], inv.[Bill To Customer Name] 
ORDER BY SUM(inv.[AR Global Total Amount]) DESC
```